# Why this Makefile execute the program infinite times?

Tags: c, linux, makefile

The make file has to compile and execute a c program for 25 seconds and than has to send the SIGHUP signal to the program, but it will be executed infinite times. Why?

Makefile code:

```
test: all clean
    valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=$VALGRINDFILE ./supermercato &
    PROCESS_TO_KILL="$!"
    (sleep 25 && pkill -SIGHUP $PROCESS_TO_KILL)
```

all: for compilation.

Comment: Why is this tagged `c`?

Comment: ...also, why _wouldn't_ it be runnable more than once? It doesn't create any `test` marker, so `test` can never be newer than the build inputs, so it's never "done" / ineligible to be run again.

Comment: BTW, use a line with three backticks in a row (and nothing else) to start and end a code segment.

Comment: The other thing is that this code would be much more robust if you used line continuations to ensure that all three commands are run inside the same shell instance (or just took out the newlines, for the same effect). If `PROCESS_TO_KILL="$!"` is run in a different shell from the `valgrind &`, then of course `$!` won't be populated in that shell. And `pkill -SIGHUP $PROCESS_TO_KILL` won't be able to see the variable either.

Comment: That said, your question says "executed infinite times", which is different (to an English speaker) from "executed for an infinite amount of time". The latter is what it looks like it would do, reading the code. ("Executed infinite times" means "executed over and over an infinite number of times", not "executed once and never stopped").

Comment: Frankly, if you're targeting a GNU system, it would be easier to run `valgrind` through the `timeout` command, and let *that* do the work of shutting it down.

Comment: Use also [remake](http://bashdb.sourceforge.net/remake/) to debug `Makefile`s

Answer (score 1):

The following code should work for you (using `timeout`):

```
test: all clean
    timeout 25 valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=$VALGRINDFILE ./supermercato
```

A few problems in your original code:

1. Makefile runs each line of the target in a separate shell. Therefore you have to join them using backslash '`\`'.
2. You should escape `$` in the shell code like this: `$$PROCESS_TO_KILL`, `$$!`.
3. `pkill` doesn't kill by PID, it kills by pattern. Need to use `kill`.

Your fixed original code:

```
test: all clean
    valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all --track-origins=yes --log-file=$VALGRINDFILE ./supermercato & \
    PROCESS_TO_KILL="$$!";\
    (sleep 25 && kill -HUP $$PROCESS_TO_KILL);  # You would need to check -SIGHUP or -HUP
```

Comment: @Gianluca That's great! Don't forget to accept my answer then